# is it possible to integrate sapui5 into liferay?

Tags: liferay, sapui5

Is it possible to develop an sapui5 application inside liferay portal?
I've saw a post which describes a liferay with Jquery (https://web.liferay.com/pt/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/using-jquery-or-any-javascript-library-in-liferay-6-0).

Anyone has tried run sapui5/openui5 application inside liferay portal?

Comment: My answers to your questions would be "yes" and "not me". Probably not, what you're looking for. Please be more specific to make this an actual question on technical content.